# Any Reference Literature on Aspect Construction of the German Language?

Tags: reference-request

I'd like to read some textbooks which introduce the German way of aspect construction. I can't read German literature so far, so those written in English will be preferred. Would anyone offer any recommendation on this?

I have a book by Comrie on aspect, but interestingly  it treats aspect construction of various languages except that of German, probably because the German way of aspect construction is on the whole more lexical than grammatical. Still, there *are* grammatical devices for aspect construction in individual cases. So I am looking for some texts on this topic, specifically focused on the German language.

Answer (score 2):

You may search in the libraries for works by **Barbara Sonnenhauser**. She is a researcher in slavonic languages but has published a number of works about the use of aspect in German too, including German dialects. There should be various journal articles, and her doctoral thesis, etc.